# I am trying to add rewarded video to my game but rewarded video events are not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

I have been stuck with this problem for many days. I am trying to add rewarded video to my game but the rewarded video events are not being called. The video ads are shown properly but the events are not being called. I have to disable a UI `gameObject` too; it is very necessary for `HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded` to work properly.

I have tried to look for a free demo project where `HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded` is being called and some work is being done, but couldn't find any such projects. I have looked for some asset in the unity asset store where admob is properly integrated in a basic game so that I could follow its code and correct my code, but I can't find such asset. I really need this to work. The project I am working on is almost complete only this problem remains.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class ADManager : MonoBehaviour {

    private string APP_ID = "ca-app-pub-4889382687991550~5546461991";

    private BannerView bannerAD;
    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
    private RewardBasedVideoAd rewardVideoAd;
    public GameObject testSprite;

    void Start() {

        // this is when you publish your app
        //MobileAds.Initialize(APP_ID);

        RequestBanner();
        RequestInterstitial();
        RequestVideoAD();

    }

    void RequestBanner() {

        string banner_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
        bannerAD = new BannerView(banner_ID, AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Bottom);

        // FOR REAL APP
        //AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

        // FOR TESTING
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .AddTestDevice("2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b").Build();

        bannerAD.LoadAd(adRequest);

    }

    void RequestInterstitial() {

        string interstitial_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(interstitial_ID);

        // FOR REAL APP
        //AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

        // FOR TESTING
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .AddTestDevice("2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b").Build();

        interstitialAd.LoadAd(adRequest);

    }

    void RequestVideoAD() {

        string video_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";
        rewardVideoAd = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;

        // FOR REAL APP
        //AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

        // FOR TESTING
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .AddTestDevice("2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b").Build();

        rewardVideoAd.LoadAd(adRequest, video_ID);

    }

    public void Display_Banner() {
        bannerAD.Show();
    }

    public void Display_InterstitialAD() {

        if (interstitialAd.IsLoaded()) {
            interstitialAd.Show();
        }

    }

    public void Display_Reward_Video() { 

        if(rewardVideoAd.IsLoaded()) {
            rewardVideoAd.Show();
        }

    }

    // HANDLE EVENTS

    public void HandleOnAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args) {
        // ad is loaded show it

        Display_Banner();

    }

    public void HandleOnAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args) {
        // ad failed to load load it again
        RequestBanner();
    }

    public void HandleOnAdOpened(object sender, EventArgs args) {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdOpened event received");
    }

    public void HandleOnAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args) {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdClosed event received");
    }

    public void HandleOnAdLeavingApplication(object sender, EventArgs args) {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdLeavingApplication event received");
    }

    void HandleBannerADEvents(bool subscribe) {

        if(subscribe) {

            // Called when an ad request has successfully loaded.
            bannerAD.OnAdLoaded += HandleOnAdLoaded;
            // Called when an ad request failed to load.
            bannerAD.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleOnAdFailedToLoad;
            // Called when an ad is clicked.
            bannerAD.OnAdOpening += HandleOnAdOpened;
            // Called when the user returned from the app after an ad click.
            bannerAD.OnAdClosed += HandleOnAdClosed;
            // Called when the ad click caused the user to leave the application.
            bannerAD.OnAdLeavingApplication += HandleOnAdLeavingApplication;

        } else {

            // Called when an ad request has successfully loaded.
            bannerAD.OnAdLoaded -= HandleOnAdLoaded;
            // Called when an ad request failed to load.
            bannerAD.OnAdFailedToLoad -= HandleOnAdFailedToLoad;
            // Called when an ad is clicked.
            bannerAD.OnAdOpening -= HandleOnAdOpened;
            // Called when the user returned from the app after an ad click.
            bannerAD.OnAdClosed -= HandleOnAdClosed;
            // Called when the ad click caused the user to leave the application.
            bannerAD.OnAdLeavingApplication -= HandleOnAdLeavingApplication;

        }

    }

    void OnEnable() {

        HandleBannerADEvents(true);
        HandleRewardedADEvents(true);
    }

    void OnDisable() {
        HandleBannerADEvents(false);
        HandleRewardedADEvents(false);
    }

    //Rewarded Video events
    public void HandleRewardBasedVideoLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleRewardBasedVideoLoaded event received");
    }

    public void HandleRewardBasedVideoFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print(
            "HandleRewardBasedVideoFailedToLoad event received with message: "
                             + args.Message);
    }

    public void HandleRewardBasedVideoOpened(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleRewardBasedVideoOpened event received");
    }

    public void HandleRewardBasedVideoStarted(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleRewardBasedVideoStarted event received");
    }

    public void HandleRewardBasedVideoClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleRewardBasedVideoClosed event received");
    }

    public void HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded(object sender, Reward args)
    {

        testSprite.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void HandleRewardBasedVideoLeftApplication(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleRewardBasedVideoLeftApplication event received");
    }

    void HandleRewardedADEvents(bool subscribe)
    {

        if (subscribe)
        {
            // Called when an ad request has successfully loaded.
            rewardVideoAd.OnAdLoaded += HandleRewardBasedVideoLoaded;
            // Called when an ad request failed to load.
            rewardVideoAd.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleRewardBasedVideoFailedToLoad;
            // Called when an ad is shown.
            rewardVideoAd.OnAdOpening += HandleRewardBasedVideoOpened;
            // Called when the ad starts to play.
            rewardVideoAd.OnAdStarted += HandleRewardBasedVideoStarted;
            // Called when the user should be rewarded for watching a video.
            rewardVideoAd.OnAdRewarded += HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;
            // Called when the ad is closed.
            rewardVideoAd.OnAdClosed += HandleRewardBasedVideoClosed;
            // Called when the ad click caused the user to leave the application.
            rewardVideoAd.OnAdLeavingApplication += HandleRewardBasedVideoLeftApplication;


        }

        else
        {
            // Called when an ad request has successfully loaded.
            rewardVideoAd.OnAdLoaded -= HandleRewardBasedVideoLoaded;
            // Called when an ad request failed to load.
            rewardVideoAd.OnAdFailedToLoad -= HandleRewardBasedVideoFailedToLoad;
            // Called when an ad is shown.
            rewardVideoAd.OnAdOpening -= HandleRewardBasedVideoOpened;
            // Called when the ad starts to play.
            rewardVideoAd.OnAdStarted -= HandleRewardBasedVideoStarted;
            // Called when the user should be rewarded for watching a video.
            rewardVideoAd.OnAdRewarded -= HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;
            // Called when the ad is closed.
            rewardVideoAd.OnAdClosed -= HandleRewardBasedVideoClosed;
            // Called when the ad click caused the user to leave the application.
            rewardVideoAd.OnAdLeavingApplication -= HandleRewardBasedVideoLeftApplication;
        }

    }

} // class
```

I also tried to implement rewarded video event in other way. In that way, the `onRewarded` video event was called and everything was working perfectly fine the first time, but it didn't work second time I tried to load the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your callback are called not in main thread. So try this one:

```
private void CallInMainThread(Action action)
{
    MobileAdsEventExecutor.ExecuteInUpdate(action);
}

public void HandleRewardBasedVideoLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    CallInMainThread(() =>
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleRewardBasedVideoLoaded event received");
    });             
}
```